# find non empty cell in col A and move contents to col B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two columns of text in excel, cols A and B.

I need a function or vb code to go through each cell in col A, find a cell which is not empty, e.g. A21, and move the contents of that cell to B22.

Then continue the search starting at A23.

The number of rows in with data in col A can be several thousand long.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1").Select

While ActiveCell.Row <= lastrow

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select

End If

Wend

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Result is this:

[image]

Comment: You could also take the formula route and put this in cell B2 and fill down: `=IF(AND(A1<>"",B1=""),A1,"")`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by writing VBA code

```
Sub moveColAToColB()
  Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
  Set currentSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Dim l As Long

  With currentSheet
    For l = 1 To.Rows.Count
      If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(l, 1).Value) Then
          .Cells(l, 2).Value = .Cells(l, 1).Value
      End If
    Next l
  End With
End Sub
```

edit: I thought you made a mistake in your description, but I didn't think you couldn't make a simple modification of easy code...

```
Sub moveColAToColB()
  Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
  Set currentSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Dim l As Long

  With currentSheet
    For l = 1 To.Rows.Count
      If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(l, 1).Value) Then
          .Cells(l + 1, 2).Value = .Cells(l, 1).Value
      l = l + 1
      End If
    Next l
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, Luboš Suk, your code moves everything from col A to B. This is not what my algorithm described.  Thanks for replying, though.

Comment: Luboš, thank you for your efforts. This does now work too.

Answer (score 0):

See code:

```
Sub MoveCellsFromColATOColB()

  For x = 21 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row ' here is the start range declared also used range
 
    Cells(x + 1, "B").Value = Cells(x, "A").Value
  
  Next x
  
End Sub
```

result:
[image]

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, your code is close to the solution, but you are effectively moving A2 to B3, which is not what I'm looking for. I need to just move A1 to B2,  but leave A2 where it is.  Then keep searching in col A until it hits the text in A4, moves it to B5, and so on.

Comment: Oh! what have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub MoveData()
    Dim K As Long, nA As Long
    Dim i As Long

    nA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 22

    For i = 1 To nA
        If Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then
            Cells(K, "B").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

for example:

[image]

Comment: Nice work Gary I understand now =)
I missunderstood the point haha.